# Basic Calculator using javafx: how to reset or restart

Tags: java, javafx, stack

I am making a basic calculator using JAVA FX and stacks. After giving the input and pressing the "=" button, I am getting the result. But  when i am try to input next expression just after getting the first result, the next expression gets appended with the result and get evaluated as INVALID(which is one of the case to evaluate the expression in my program). What I want is if I press any number button after pressing "=" for previous expression, it should clear the TextField and take the next expression as input and evaluate that upon pressing "=". I think i should put the "Evaluation" part in a loop, but cannot figure out how to do it.

```
package application;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Stack;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;



public class Main extends Application {

/*The keyboard key values*/
private static final String[][] key_values = {
        { "7", "8", "9", "/" },
        { "4", "5", "6", "*" },
        { "1", "2", "3", "-" },
        { "0", "c", "=", "+" }
};
private Button btn[][] = new Button[4][4]; //all the keys
TextField calculator_screen;  //the calculator screen


int flag=0,repeat=0;
String exp;
String temp;
String sample = "0";
String sample2 = "0";
Double num1=0.0,num2=0.0,sum=0.0;
Double checkNum=0.0;
Double temp_sum=0.0;
Stack <String>stack = new Stack<>();
Stack <String>stack_new = new Stack<>();
//MyStack s = new MyStack();
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    launch(args);
    //System.out.print("123456789");

}


@Override public void start(Stage stage) {

    /*The outside layout*/
    final VBox layout = new VBox(30); //the size vertically

    /*The inside layout for keys or buttons*/
    TilePane keypad = new TilePane(); //even it is called keypad, it is a layout
    keypad.setVgap(7);
    keypad.setHgap(7); //set the gap between keys


    /*Create Calculator Screen */
    calculator_screen =  new TextField();
    calculator_screen.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;"); //set the style of the screen
    calculator_screen.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT); //make the screen in the center of the calculator
    calculator_screen.setEditable(false); //make sure the screen cannot be typed in manually
    calculator_screen.setPrefWidth(500); //set the windth of the screen

    /*Create Calculator keyboard*/
    keypad.setPrefColumns(key_values[0].length); //set the preferred number of columns

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
        {
            btn[i][j] = new Button(key_values[i][j]);
            final int a = i;
            final int b = j;

            /*Add button event*/
            btn[i][j].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    calculator_screen.appendText(key_values[a][b]);
                    exp = calculator_screen.getText().toString();

                }

        }
                    );

            keypad.getChildren().add(btn[i][j]);
        }
    }


    btn[3][1].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    calculator_screen.setText("");
                }

            });


    //-------------When "=" button is pressed--------

    btn[3][2].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //System.out.println("=============");
            //System.out.println("Expression = "+ exp);


            //--------------Pushing the elements to the stack-------------------

            exp = exp+"\n";
            char [] ch = exp.toCharArray();
            int len = ch.length;
            int i=0;

            for(int j=0;j<len;j++)
            {
                if(ch[j]>='0' && ch[j]<='9')
                {
                    //System.out.println("Digit = "+ ch[j]);
                    i=j;
                    sample = "0";
                    while(ch[i]>='0' && ch[i]<='9' && i < len)//To check if there is a more than 1 digit nummber.
                    {
                        if(ch[i]>='0' && ch[i]<='9')
                        {
                            System.out.println("Digit = "+ ch[i]);
                            System.out.println("sample before = "+ sample);
                            sample = sample+exp.charAt(i);
                            System.out.println("sample after = "+ sample);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    stack.push(sample);
                    //System.out.println("hiii");
                    j=i-1;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Sign = "+ ch[i]);

                    stack.push(Character.toString(ch[i]));
                }
            }
            temp=stack.pop();
            int size= stack.size();
            System.out.println("Size of stack = "+ size);
            //if(stack.size()==null)

            //-----------Reversing the order of the stack-------------

            while(!stack.isEmpty())
            {
                sample2=stack.pop();
                stack_new.push(sample2);
            }


            //-----------Evaluating the expression--------------------

            while(!stack_new.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("--------");


                temp=stack_new.peek();
                System.out.println("Stack item = "+temp);
                int type =checkString(temp) ;

                if(type == 0)
                {
                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                    stack_new.pop();
                    //System.out.println("Stack item = "+sum);

                }
                else if(type ==5)
                {
                    System.out.println("Stack Empty");
                    //stack.pop();
                    flag=2;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    int op=checkString(temp);
                    stack_new.pop();
                    //System.out.println("Stack item = "+sum);
                    temp=stack_new.peek();
                    type =checkString(temp) ;
                    if(type!=0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid");
                        flag=2;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        num2=Double.parseDouble(temp);
                        if(op==1)
                        {
                            temp_sum=num1+num2;
                            System.out.println("Sum = "+ temp_sum);
                        }
                        else if(op==2)
                        {
                            temp_sum=num1-num2;
                            System.out.println("Diff = "+ temp_sum);
                        }
                        else if(op==3)
                        {
                            temp_sum=num1*num2;
                            System.out.println("Product = "+ temp_sum);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(num2!=0)
                            {
                                temp_sum=num1/num2;
                                System.out.println("Division = "+ temp_sum);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("Cannot divide by 0");
                                flag=1;
                            }
                        }
                        num1=temp_sum;
                    }
                    stack_new.pop();
                }

            }
            System.out.println("result = "+ temp_sum);
            if(flag==0)
                calculator_screen.setText(temp_sum.toString());
            else if(flag==1)
            {
                calculator_screen.setText("Error");
                calculator_screen.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");

            }
            else if(flag==2)
            {
                calculator_screen.setText("Invalid Expression");
                calculator_screen.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");

            }


        }

        public int checkString(String temp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(temp.length()==1)
        {

            char ch=temp.charAt(0);
            if(ch=='+')
                return 1;
            else if(ch=='-')
                return 2;
            else if(ch=='*')
                return 3;
            else if(ch=='/')
                return 4;
            else 
                return 5;

        }
        else
            return 0;
        }

    });



    /*Put the calculator screen and keypad into a VBox layout*/
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    //layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #797983; -fx-padding: 20; -fx-font-size: 20;");
    layout.getChildren().addAll(calculator_screen, keypad);
    calculator_screen.prefWidthProperty().bind(keypad.widthProperty());


    /*Show the window*/
    stage.setTitle("Calculator");
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

}
```

Comment: I would probably just use a `boolean needsReset` which you can set to `true` when you evaluate the expression (on pressing `=`). Then check it in the button handlers and clear the text if it's true (and then set to false).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for your question.

```
import java.util.Stack;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;



public class Main extends Application {

/*The keyboard key values*/
private static final String[][] key_values = {
        { "7", "8", "9", "/" },
        { "4", "5", "6", "*" },
        { "1", "2", "3", "-" },
        { "0", "c", "=", "+" }
};
private Button btn[][] = new Button[4][4]; //all the keys
TextField calculator_screen;  //the calculator screen

boolean isEqualCalled = false;
int flag=0,repeat=0;
String exp;
String temp;
String sample = "0";
String sample2 = "0";
Double num1=0.0,num2=0.0,sum=0.0;
Double checkNum=0.0;
Double temp_sum=0.0;
Stack <String>stack = new Stack<>();
Stack <String>stack_new = new Stack<>();
//MyStack s = new MyStack();
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    launch(args);
    //System.out.print("123456789");

}


@Override public void start(Stage stage) {

    /*The outside layout*/
    final VBox layout = new VBox(30); //the size vertically

    /*The inside layout for keys or buttons*/
    TilePane keypad = new TilePane(); //even it is called keypad, it is a layout
    keypad.setVgap(7);
    keypad.setHgap(7); //set the gap between keys


    /*Create Calculator Screen */
    calculator_screen =  new TextField();
    calculator_screen.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;"); //set the style of the screen
    calculator_screen.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT); //make the screen in the center of the calculator
    calculator_screen.setEditable(false); //make sure the screen cannot be typed in manually
    calculator_screen.setPrefWidth(500); //set the windth of the screen

    /*Create Calculator keyboard*/
    keypad.setPrefColumns(key_values[0].length); //set the preferred number of columns

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
        {
            btn[i][j] = new Button(key_values[i][j]);
            final int a = i;
            final int b = j;

            /*Add button event*/
            btn[i][j].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    if(isEqualCalled){
                        calculator_screen.clear();
                        isEqualCalled = false;
                    }
                    calculator_screen.appendText(key_values[a][b]);
                    exp = calculator_screen.getText().toString();

                }

        }

                    );

            keypad.getChildren().add(btn[i][j]);
        }
    }

    btn[3][1].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    calculator_screen.setText("");
                }

            });


    //-------------When "=" button is pressed--------

    btn[3][2].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //System.out.println("=============");
            //System.out.println("Expression = "+ exp);
            isEqualCalled = true;

            //--------------Pushing the elements to the stack-------------------
            exp = exp+"\n";
            char [] ch = exp.toCharArray();
            int len = ch.length;
            int i=0;

            for(int j=0;j<len;j++)
            {
                if(ch[j]>='0' && ch[j]<='9')
                {
                    //System.out.println("Digit = "+ ch[j]);
                    i=j;
                    sample = "0";
                    while(ch[i]>='0' && ch[i]<='9' && i < len)//To check if there is a more than 1 digit nummber.
                    {
                        if(ch[i]>='0' && ch[i]<='9')
                        {
                            System.out.println("Digit = "+ ch[i]);
                            System.out.println("sample before = "+ sample);
                            sample = sample+exp.charAt(i);
                            System.out.println("sample after = "+ sample);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    stack.push(sample);
                    //System.out.println("hiii");
                    j=i-1;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Sign = "+ ch[i]);

                    stack.push(Character.toString(ch[i]));
                }
            }
            temp=stack.pop();
            int size= stack.size();
            System.out.println("Size of stack = "+ size);
            //if(stack.size()==null)

            //-----------Reversing the order of the stack-------------

            while(!stack.isEmpty())
            {
                sample2=stack.pop();
                stack_new.push(sample2);
            }


            //-----------Evaluating the expression--------------------

            while(!stack_new.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("--------");


                temp=stack_new.peek();
                System.out.println("Stack item = "+temp);
                int type =checkString(temp) ;

                if(type == 0)
                {
                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                    stack_new.pop();
                    //System.out.println("Stack item = "+sum);

                }
                else if(type ==5)
                {
                    System.out.println("Stack Empty");
                    //stack.pop();
                    flag=2;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    int op=checkString(temp);
                    stack_new.pop();
                    //System.out.println("Stack item = "+sum);
                    temp=stack_new.peek();
                    type =checkString(temp) ;
                    if(type!=0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid");
                        flag=2;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        num2=Double.parseDouble(temp);
                        if(op==1)
                        {
                            temp_sum=num1+num2;
                            System.out.println("Sum = "+ temp_sum);
                        }
                        else if(op==2)
                        {
                            temp_sum=num1-num2;
                            System.out.println("Diff = "+ temp_sum);
                        }
                        else if(op==3)
                        {
                            temp_sum=num1*num2;
                            System.out.println("Product = "+ temp_sum);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(num2!=0)
                            {
                                temp_sum=num1/num2;
                                System.out.println("Division = "+ temp_sum);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("Cannot divide by 0");
                                flag=1;
                            }
                        }
                        num1=temp_sum;
                    }
                    stack_new.pop();
                }

            }
            System.out.println("result = "+ temp_sum);
            if(flag==0)
                calculator_screen.setText(temp_sum.toString());
            else if(flag==1)
            {
                calculator_screen.setText("Error");
                calculator_screen.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");

            }
            else if(flag==2)
            {
                calculator_screen.setText("Invalid Expression");
                calculator_screen.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");

            }


        }

        public int checkString(String temp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(temp.length()==1)
        {

            char ch=temp.charAt(0);
            if(ch=='+')
                return 1;
            else if(ch=='-')
                return 2;
            else if(ch=='*')
                return 3;
            else if(ch=='/')
                return 4;
            else 
                return 5;

        }
        else
            return 0;
        }

    });



    /*Put the calculator screen and keypad into a VBox layout*/
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    //layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #797983; -fx-padding: 20; -fx-font-size: 20;");
    layout.getChildren().addAll(calculator_screen, keypad);
    calculator_screen.prefWidthProperty().bind(keypad.widthProperty());


    /*Show the window*/
    stage.setTitle("Calculator");
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

}
```

Use this code and check the isEqualCalled variable and follow. You will understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear a JTextField (or JTextArea), simply plug in the following line into a button action:

```
yourTextFieldVariable.setText(null);
```

This will clear the field of the variable when the button with the line is clicked.